# Area of curve trace by a function which satisfies a given condition.

Tags: 3d

If point $P(a,b,c)$ satisfies $a-b+c=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=4$. The point $P$ traces a plane figure whose area is $A$. Then $\lfloor A\rfloor $ is

solution I try

Let an equation of plane is $ax+by+cz+d=0$. Now distance of point $P(a,b,c)$ from origin is $$\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=\frac{d}{2}$$

How do I solve that problem? Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In, the $a$-$b$-$c$ 3-dimensional Euclidean space (not $x$-$y$-$z$), the second condition $a^2+b^2+c^2=4$ is (the surface of) a sphere with radius $2$.

The first condition $a - b + c = 0$ is a plane that passes through the origin $(a,b,c) = (0,0,0)$, which is also the center of the sphere.

Therefore, the intersection (where both conditions are satisfied) is a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) of the said sphere, hence its radius is also $r = 2$.

The area of such circle is $A = \pi r^2 = 4\pi \approx 12.56637\ldots$, and the floor of the area $\lfloor A\rfloor$ (I'm not sure why you want that) is thus $12$.